# sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib not working on Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gcc, c++

I've got the latest version of Linux Mint 16 (64 bit) and in Netbeans I am compiling a project in 32 bit mode. I get the error that I am missing `bits/config.h`. I think this is because I am in 32-bit mode for compiling. I tried installing:

> sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib

but after a few lines it said:

> E: unable to locate package multilib

Could someone please help? This line worked for a gcc 4.7 problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit